# How do I access elements that are not 0 in a partially initialized array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to multiply all of the values the user inputs for the array. The problem is if fewer than 50 array elements are used than the result is always 0. Is there a way to access only the elements the user entered?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int SIZE = 50;
        int[] array = new int[SIZE];
        int index = 0;
        int aScore = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for the array for position {0} (or 0 to stop):", (index + 1));
            aScore = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(aScore >= 0)
            {
                array[index++] = aScore;
            }
        }while (aScore != 0 && index < SIZE);


        Console.WriteLine("The product of the array is: {0}", SumArray(array));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int SumArray(int[] array)
    {
        int product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            product *= array[i];
        }
        return product;
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you use a list?

Comment: I see some C habits. Gathering variables at the beginning of the function and initializing them. Fixed size buffers. for-Loops. C# works better if you leave those behind.

Answer (score 2):

```
var values = array.Where(x => x != 0).ToArray();
```

Make sure you have `using System.Linq;`

As Tim said above, using a `List<int>` would be the preferred way to approach this problem though.
If you use a `List<int>` then you can use the LINQ Aggregate function like this

```
var ints = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var product = ints.Aggregate((total, nextNum) => total * nextNum); // product = 120
```

EDIT

Here's a complete example of how I'd do it

```
private static void Main()
{
    const int maxScores = 50;
    int index = 0;
    int nextScore = 0;
    var scores = new List<int>();

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for the array for position {0} (or 0 to stop):", ++index);
        nextScore = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (nextScore > 0)
            scores.Add(nextScore);
    } while (nextScore != 0 && index < maxScores);

    Console.WriteLine("The product of the scores is : {0}",
        scores.Aggregate((total, next) => total * next));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for 0 before multiplying:

```
 if (array[i] != 0)
       product *= array[i]
```

Also if you want to 'sum' array, the operation should be `+=`

Answer (score 0):

Your method

```
static int SumArray(int[] array)
    {
        int product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            product *= array[i];
        }
        return product;
    }
```

should be look like this

```
static int SumArray(int[] array)
    {
        int product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] != 0)
            {
                 product *= array[i];
            }
        }
        return product;
    }
```

and also

```
do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for the array for position {0} (or 0 to stop):", (index + 1));
            aScore = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(aScore >= 0)
            {
                array[index++] = aScore;
            }
        }while (aScore != 0 && index < SIZE);
```

this part is not a good practice for achieving your goal, because you put the record with value 0 in the array too.You can replace that with

> if(aScore > 0)

if you want, but I would suggest you to use List instead of an array, and you'll not have  a problem with additional unnecessary elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could dispense with your `SumArray()` method completely and just say:

```
int product = array
              .Where( n => n != 0 )
              .Aggregate( 1 , (m,n) => m*n )
              ;
Console.WriteLine( "The product of the array is: {0}" ,
   ) ;
```

You could use a `List<int>` (which is actually just an adjustable length array under the covers) and not worry about it:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
  List<int> scores = new List<int>() ;

  while ( true )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Enter a value for the array for position {0} (or 0 to stop):" ,
      1+scores.Count
      ) ;
    int score = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() ) ;

    if ( score == 0 ) break ;

    values.Add(score);

  }

  int product = scores.Aggregate( 1 , (m,n) => m*n ) ;
  Console.WriteLine( "The product of the array is: {0}" , product ) ;

  return ;
}
```

Or you can dispense with maintaining the collection completely and just tote things up as you go:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
  int sum     = 0 ;
  int n       = 0 ;
  int product = 1 ;

  while ( true )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Enter a value for the array for position {0} (or 0 to stop):" ,
      1+scores.Count
      ) ;
    int score = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() ) ;

    if ( score == 0 ) break ;

    sum     += score ;
    product *= score ;
    n++ ;

  }

  Console.WriteLine( "The product of the array is: {0}" , product ) ;
  Console.WriteLine( "The sum of {0} scores is {1}" , n , sum ) ;
  Console.WriteLine( "The mean score is {0}" , (double)sum/(double)n ) ;

  return ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you test `if (array[i] > 0)` inside the for loop, this test can be made several times. For example, if you inform three numbers, the coinditional will be tested 47 times.

So, if you found a zero, is better break the loop.

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->

static int SumArray(int[] array)
{
    int product = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0) break;
        product *= array[i];
    }
    return product;
}
```